# Analyzing Cyclic Behavior of the Temperature in an Office Building

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

let us consider following code

```
>> load officetemp.mat
Fs = 1/(60*30);   % Sample rate is 1 sample every 30 minutes
t = (0:length(temp)-1)/Fs;
>> NFFT = length(temp);              % Number of FFT points
F = (0 : 1/NFFT : 1/2-1/NFFT)*Fs; % Frequency vector

TEMP = fft(temp,NFFT);
TEMP(1) = 0; % remove the DC component for better visualization

helperFrequencyAnalysisPlot2(F*60*60*24*7,abs(TEMP(1:NFFT/2)),...
  'Frequency (cycles/week)','Magnitude',[],[],[0 10])
>>
```

it is used to Analyzing Cyclic Behavior of the Temperature in an Office Building ,Problem statement is that

a set of temperature measurements in an office building during the winter season. Measurements were taken every 30 minutes for about 16.5 weeks. Look at the time domain data with the time axis scaled to weeks. Could there be any periodic behavior on this data?

after running that code   we have following graphic 
[image]

while it is easy to use this code, i want to use periodogram , for which power spectrum estimation with defualt rectangular window and default DFT point is

> > [pxx,f]=periodogram(temp,[],[],Fs);
> >     plot(f,pxx)
> >     but figure is that
> >         [image]

could you help me please what happens? thanks in advance, for addition information, question is taken from here

http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/practical-introduction-to-frequency-domain-analysis.html

Comment: Posting this to stats.stackexchange.com might get you some good answers that you won't find here.  (But you might also find some good answers of a different kind here.)

Comment: can i leave this question here or i have to delete?

Comment: It looks like a axis scaling issue where the content of the DC bin is so large that the rest of the spectrum cannot be seen. Try removing the mean from the input vector or just settting the ylimits to ignore the DC component.